# Products in Magento - SKUs from a category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sku, dynamic

Would you have any way to get product SKUs from a category? For example, I have a category with `id = 13` and I need to get the SKUs of these products dynamically, so I can do checks that I created in my code.

And I would need to save these SKUs of these products in an array so I can do a check in my code, as I currently "pick up" these SKUs manually by placing them in an array.

**Code created in a controller:**

```
public function isCartaoAddAction(){
            $array_de_skus_de_cartoes = array(45,60,80,90,102,103,104,105); //SKUs products
            $isCartaoAdicionado = 0;
            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {    
                foreach ($array_de_skus_de_cartoes as $sku) {
                    if($sku == $item->getProduct()->getSku()) {
                        $isCartaoAdicionado = 1;
                        $cartao_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($sku);
                    }
                }
            }
            if($isCartaoAdicionado == 1) {
                echo json_encode(array('adicionado' => '1','id_produto' => $cartao_id));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('adicionado' => '','id_produto' => ''));
            }
        }
```

Comment: you want all the SKUs that are assigned to category id = 13.. Right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code to get all SKUs

**Update:**
Instead of Using multiple `foreach` loop, you can use PHP `in_array` function.

```
<?php
public function isCartaoAddAction(){
    $categoryId = 13;
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryId)
                ->getProductCollection();
    foreach($collection as $product){
         $array_de_skus_de_cartoes[] = $product->getSku();
    }
    //$array_de_skus_de_cartoes = array(45,60,80,90,102,103,104,105); //SKUs products
    $isCartaoAdicionado = 0;
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {           
        if(in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $array_de_skus_de_cartoes)) {
            $sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
            $isCartaoAdicionado = 1;
            $cartao_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($sku);
        }
    }
    if($isCartaoAdicionado == 1) {
        echo json_encode(array('adicionado' => '1','id_produto' => $cartao_id));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('adicionado' => '','id_produto' => ''));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It worked fine, however for my case I'm having a hard time modifying it to my code, since before I took these SKUs manually through an array and I would need to put the SKUs of that category in array to be able to do a check that it contains in my code .

Comment: basically what is your requirement? what you need to check without adding all the SKUs in array?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I did, along with the verification.

Comment: But basically, I'd need to save those SKUs in an array.

Comment: Check my updated answer. This is what you want or may different requirement.

Comment: I tested, but it did not work out.

Comment: your requirement is not clear to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65800/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-matheus-portela).